# How do I reset the values of input x and y?

Tags: python, input

Take two integers **x** and **y** as inputs from the console using **input()** function. For each assignment operator (**=**, **+=**, **-=**, and ***=**), print to the console, the result of applying these operators on the two input integers as shown in the example.

**Assumption:**

- y is a non-zero integer

**Hint:** Before every assignment operation, reset the values of x and y to the initial values.

This is my code line:

```
x = int(input("x: "))
y = int(input("y: "))

x = y
print("x = y:", x)

x += y
print("x += y:", x)

x -= y
print("x -= y:", x)

x *= y
print("x *= y:", x)
```

How do I reset the values of x and y to the initial values??

**Sample Input and Output:**

```
x: 20
y: 30
x = y: 30
x += y: 50
x -= y: -10
x *= y: 600
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the variable 'x' is constantly changing during the process, you can save the input x to another variable, and then reset to this value continuously

```
base_x = int(input("x: "))
y = int(input("y: "))

x = y
print("x = y:", x)
x = base_x

x += y
print("x += y:", x)
x = base_x

x -= y
print("x -= y:", x)
x = base_x

x *= y
print("x *= y:", x)
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you are not modyfing y since you are only reassigning x.

I think the only way to reinitialize x is that every time, before every operation, you assign `x=y`.

Learning how to debug can help you understand what's happening during the execution of the code and how the variables are modified

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, I assume those initial values are the input values. So it is better to perform these operations (+, -, * and /) with copy of the initial values like the following code:

```
x_initial = int(input("x: "))
y_initial = int(input("y: "))

x = x_initial 
y = y_initial

x = y
print("x = y:", x)

# Reset
x = x_initial 
y = y_initial

x += y
print("x += y:", x)

# Reset
x = x_initial 
y = y_initial

x -= y
print("x -= y:", x)

# Reset
x = x_initial 
y = y_initial

x *= y
print("x *= y:", x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Get intial input, unpack, then assign x and y to initial value before each operation to reset.

```
init = int(input("x: ")), int(input("y: "))

x, y = init
x = y
print("x = y:", x)

x, y = init
x += y
print("x += y:", x)

x, y = init
x -= y
print("x -= y:", x)

x, y = init
x *= y
print("x *= y:", x)

# x: 20
# y: 30
# x = y: 30
# x += y: 50
# x -= y: -10
# x *= y: 600
```